# clustering in excel

Tags: excel, cluster-analysis

Did anyone of you know if it is possible to implement clustering algorithms, like k-means, dbscan, in Excel without the use of VBA??

If it is possible, can you give me a little help how one can do it? (an little example would help me)

Thanks a lot in adavance

Claude

Comment: Through google I found this: which claims [to
perform clustering in Microsoft Excel 2007 without using macros.](http://www.ijcaonline.org/volume11/number7/pxc3872144.pdf) I'm not really familiar with cluster-analysis so I can't confirm it.

Comment: Is there a deep intrinsic reason it needs to be done in Excel? Why not dump a table and use something that will be faster, more appropriate and more flexible?

Answer (score 1):

**Why would you**? Excel is not meant for this.

Clustering algorithms often benefit greatly from using **index structures**, organizing the data in memory in a smart way. For example R*-trees, kd-tree etc.

This makes a huge difference. DBSCAN without an index is of complexity `O(n^2)`, while with index structures it is only of `O(n log n)` complexity.

You probably could do this in VBA (which isn't really Excel anymore, but Visual Basic), I guess. But it makes more sense to use existing code for R*-trees etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.neilson.co.za/k-means-cluster-analysis-in-microsoft-excel/)

**The k-Means Algorithm**

The k-Means algorithm is an iteration of the following steps until stability is achieved i.e. the cluster assignments of individual records are no longer changing.

Determine the coordinates of the centroids. (initially the centroids are random, unique points, thereafter the mean coordinates of the members of the cluster are assigned to the centroids).
Determine the euclidean distance of each record to each centroid.
Group records with their nearest centroid.
The Code

Firstly I have created a private type to represent our records and centroids and created two class level arrays to hold them as well as a class level variable to hold the table on which the analysis is being performed.

```
Private Type Records
    Dimension() As Double
    Distance() As Double
    Cluster As Integer
End Type

Dim Table As Range
Dim Record() As Records
Dim Centroid() As Records
User Interface
```

The following method,`Run()` can be used as a starting point and hooked to buttons etc.

```
Sub Run()
'Run k-Means
   If Not kMeansSelection Then
        Call MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "kMeans Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

Next, a method is created that prompts the user to select the table to be analysed and to input the desired number of clusters that the data should be grouped into. The function does not require any arguments and returns a boolean indicating whether or not any errors have been encountered.

```
Function kMeansSelection() As Boolean

'Get user table selection
   On Error Resume Next
    Set Table = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                                     "Please select the range to analyse.", _
                                     title:="Specify Range", Type:=8)

    If Table Is Nothing Then Exit Function        'Cancelled

    'Check table dimensions
   If Table.Rows.Count < 4 Or Table.columns.Count < 2 Then
        Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, Source:="k-Means Cluster Analysis", Description:="Table has insufficent rows or columns."
    End If

    'Get number of clusters
   Dim numClusters As Integer
    numClusters = Application.InputBox("Specify Number of Clusters", "k Means Cluster Analysis", Type:=1)

    If Not numClusters > 0 Or numClusters = False Then
        Exit Function        'Cancelled
   End If
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If kMeans(Table, numClusters) Then
            outputClusters
        End If
    End If

kMeansSelection_Error:
    kMeansSelection = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

If a table has been selected and a number of clusters defined appropriately, the kMeans (Table, numClusters) method is invoked with the Table and number of clusters as parameters.

If the `kMeans (Table, numClusters)` method executes without errors, a final method, outputClusters() is invoked which creates a new worksheet in the active workbook and outputs the results of the analysis.

**Assigning Records to Clusters**

This is where the actual analysis of the records takes place and cluster assignments are made.
First and foremost, the method is declared with Function `kMeans(Table As Range, Clusters As Integer) As Boolean`. the Function takes two parameters, the table being analysed as an Excel Range object and Clusters, an integer denoting the number of clusters to be created.

```
Function kMeans(Table As Range, Clusters As Integer) As Boolean
'Table - Range of data to group. Records (Rows) are grouped according to attributes/dimensions(columns)
'Clusters - Number of clusters to reduce records into.

    On Error Resume Next

    'Script Performance Variables
   Dim PassCounter As Integer

    'Initialize Data Arrays
   ReDim Record(2 To Table.Rows.Count)
    Dim r As Integer        'record
   Dim d As Integer        'dimension index
   Dim d2 As Integer        'dimension index
   Dim c As Integer        'centroid index
   Dim c2 As Integer        'centroid index
   Dim di As Integer        'distance

    Dim x As Double        'Variable Distance Placeholder
   Dim y As Double        'Variable Distance Placeholder
```

`On error Resume Next` is used to pass errors up to to the calling method, and a number of array index variables are declared. x and y are declared for later use in mathematical operations.

The first step is to size the `Record()` array to the number of rows in the table. (2 to Table.Rows.Count) is used as it is assumed (and required) that the first row of the table holds the column titles.

Then, for every record in the `Record()` array, the Record type’s `Dimension()` array is sized to the number of columns (again assuming that the first column holds the row titles) and the `Distance()` array is sized to the number of clusters. An internal loop then assigns the values of the columns in the row to the `Dimension()` array.

For r = LBound(Record) To UBound(Record)
    'Initialize Dimension Value Arrays
   ReDim Record(r).Dimension(2 To Table.columns.Count)
    'Initialize Distance Arrays
   ReDim Record(r).Distance(1 To Clusters)
    For d = LBound(Record(r).Dimension) To UBound(Record(r).Dimension)
        Record(r).Dimension(d) = Table.Rows(r).Cells(d).Value
    Next d
Next r

In much the same way, the initial centroids must be initialized. I have assigned the coordinates of the first few records as the initial centroids coordinates checking that each new centroid has unique coordinates. If not, the script simply moves on to the next record until a unique set of coordinates is found for the centroid.

Euclidean DistanceThe method used to calculate centroid uniqueness here is almost exactly the same as the method used later on to calculate the distance between individual records and the centroids. Here the centroids are checked for uniqueness by measuring their dimensions’ distance from 0.

```
    'Initialize Initial Centroid Arrays
   ReDim Centroid(1 To Clusters)
    Dim uniqueCentroid As Boolean

    For c = LBound(Centroid) To UBound(Centroid)
        'Initialize Centroid Dimension Depth
       ReDim Centroid(c).Dimension(2 To Table.columns.Count)

        'Initialize record index to next record
       r = LBound(Record) + c - 2

        Do        ' Loop to ensure new centroid is unique
           r = r + 1        'Increment record index throughout loop to find unique record to use as a centroid

            'Assign record dimensions to centroid
           For d = LBound(Centroid(c).Dimension) To UBound(Centroid(c).Dimension)
                Centroid(c).Dimension(d) = Record(r).Dimension(d)
            Next d

            uniqueCentroid = True

            For c2 = LBound(Centroid) To c - 1

                'Loop Through Record Dimensions and check if all are the same
               x = 0
                y = 0
                For d2 = LBound(Centroid(c).Dimension) To _
                    UBound(Centroid(c).Dimension)
                    x = x + Centroid(c).Dimension(d2) ^ 2
                    y = y + Centroid(c2).Dimension(d2) ^ 2
                Next d2

                uniqueCentroid = Not Sqr(x) = Sqr(y)
                If Not uniqueCentroid Then Exit For
            Next c2

        Loop Until uniqueCentroid

    Next c
The next step is to calculate each records distance from each centroid and assign the record to the nearest cluster.
```

`Dim lowestDistance As Double` – The lowestDistance variable holds the shortest distance measured between a record and centroid thus far for evaluation against subsequent measurements.
`Dim lastCluster As Integer` – The lastCluster variable holds the cluster a record is assigned to before any new assignments are made and is used to evaluate whether or not stability has been achieved.
`Dim ClustersStable As Boolean` – The cluster assignment and centroid re-calculation phases are repeated until `ClustersStable = true.`

Dim lowestDistance As Double
Dim lastCluster As Integer
Dim ClustersStable As Boolean

Do        'While Clusters are not Stable

```
PassCounter = PassCounter + 1
ClustersStable = True        'Until Proved otherwise

'Loop Through Records
```

For r = LBound(Record) To UBound(Record)

```
    lastCluster = Record(r).Cluster
    lowestDistance = 0        'Reset lowest distance

    'Loop through record distances to centroids
   For c = LBound(Centroid) To UBound(Centroid)

        '======================================================
       '           Calculate Euclidean Distance
       '======================================================
       ' d(p,q) = Sqr((q1 - p1)^2 + (q2 - p2)^2 + (q3 - p3)^2)
       '------------------------------------------------------
       ' X = (q1 - p1)^2 + (q2 - p2)^2 + (q3 - p3)^2
       ' d(p,q) = X

        x = 0
        y = 0
        'Loop Through Record Dimensions
       For d = LBound(Record(r).Dimension) To _
            UBound(Record(r).Dimension)
            y = Record(r).Dimension(d) - Centroid(c).Dimension(d)
            y = y ^ 2
            x = x + y
        Next d

        x = Sqr(x)        'Get square root

        'If distance to centroid is lowest (or first pass) assign record to centroid cluster.
       If c = LBound(Centroid) Or x < lowestDistance Then
            lowestDistance = x
            'Assign distance to centroid to record
           Record(r).Distance(c) = lowestDistance
            'Assign record to centroid
           Record(r).Cluster = c
        End If
    Next c

    'Only change if true
   If ClustersStable Then ClustersStable = Record(r).Cluster = lastCluster

Next r
```

Once each record is assigned to a cluster, the centroids of the clusters are re-positioned to the mean coordinates of the cluster. After the centroids have moved, each records closest centroid is re-evaluated and the process is iterated until stability is achieved (i.e. cluster assignments are no longer changing).

```
'Move Centroids to calculated cluster average
       For c = LBound(Centroid) To UBound(Centroid)        'For every cluster

            'Loop through cluster dimensions
           For d = LBound(Centroid(c).Dimension) To _
                UBound(Centroid(c).Dimension)

                Centroid(c).Cluster = 0        'Reset nunber of records in cluster
               Centroid(c).Dimension(d) = 0        'Reset centroid dimensions

                'Loop Through Records
               For r = LBound(Record) To UBound(Record)

                    'If Record is in Cluster then
                   If Record(r).Cluster = c Then
                        'Use to calculate avg dimension for records in cluster

                        'Add to number of records in cluster
                       Centroid(c).Cluster = Centroid(c).Cluster + 1
                        'Add record dimension to cluster dimension for later division
                       Centroid(c).Dimension(d) = Centroid(c).Dimension(d) + _
                                                   Record(r).Dimension(d)

                    End If

                Next r

                'Assign Average Dimension Distance
               Centroid(c).Dimension(d) = Centroid(c).Dimension(d) / _
                                           Centroid(c).Cluster
            Next d
        Next c

    Loop Until ClustersStable

    kMeans = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

**Displaying the Results**

the `outputClusters()` method outputs the results in two tables. The first table contains each record name and the assigned cluster number, and the second contains the centroid coordinates.

```
Function outputClusters() As Boolean

    Dim c As Integer        'Centroid Index
   Dim r As Integer        'Row Index
   Dim d As Integer        'Dimension Index

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oSheet = addWorksheet("Cluster Analysis", ActiveWorkbook)

    'Loop Through Records
   Dim rowNumber As Integer
    rowNumber = 1

    'Output Headings
   With oSheet.Rows(rowNumber)
        With .Cells(1)
            .Value = "Row Title"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With .Cells(2)
            .Value = "Centroid"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End With

    'Print by Row
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1        'Blank Row
   For r = LBound(Record) To UBound(Record)
        oSheet.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(1).Value = Table.Rows(r).Cells(1).Value
        oSheet.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(2).Value = Record(r).Cluster
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next r

    'Print Centroids - Headings
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    For d = LBound(Centroid(LBound(Centroid)).Dimension) To UBound(Centroid(LBound(Centroid)).Dimension)
        With oSheet.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(d)
            .Value = Table.Rows(1).Cells(d).Value
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    Next d

    'Print Centroids
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    For c = LBound(Centroid) To UBound(Centroid)
        With oSheet.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(1)
            .Value = "Centroid " & c
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        'Loop through cluster dimensions
       For d = LBound(Centroid(c).Dimension) To UBound(Centroid(c).Dimension)
            oSheet.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(d).Value = Centroid(c).Dimension(d)
        Next d
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next c

    oSheet.columns.AutoFit        '//AutoFit columns to contents

outputClusters_Error:
    outputClusters = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

It’s unlikely that this type of output will be of much use, but it serves to demonstrate the way in which the record cluster assignments or cluster records can be accessed in your own solutions.

The `outputClusters()` function makes use of another custom method: addWorksheet() which adds a worksheet to the specified/active workbook with the specified name. If a worksheet with the same name already exists, the outputClusters() function adds/increments a number appended to the worksheet name. The `WorksheetExists()` Function is also included in the following:

```
Function addWorksheet(Name As String, Optional Workbook As Workbook) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    '// If a Workbook wasn't specified, use the active workbook
   If Workbook Is Nothing Then Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim Num As Integer
    '// If a worksheet(s) exist with the same name, add/increment a number after the name
   While WorksheetExists(Name, Workbook)
        Num = Num + 1
        If InStr(Name, " (") > 0 Then Name = Left(Name, InStr(Name, " ("))
        Name = Name & " (" & Num & ")"
    Wend

    '//Add a sheet to the workbook
   Set addWorksheet = Workbook.Worksheets.Add

    '//Name the sheet
   addWorksheet.Name = Name
End Function

Public Function WorksheetExists(WorkSheetName As String, Workbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = (Workbook.Sheets(WorkSheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```